# How can I restrict values of a string column in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to build a Rails database migration using ga Postgres 9.5 database in which I have a string column

```
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.string transaction_type, null: false
```

but I would like to restrict the values of the column to only certain strings.  Is there any way I can build that into my migration?  If so, how would that look?

Comment: Can you add more details about what you're trying to do? You could use an enum instead a string data type.

Comment: That sounds like it could solve my problem.  With "enum", could I restrict the column to only have certain values?

Comment: `enum` wouldn't restrict things inside the database, you'd still be leaving all the validation up to Rails and (AFAIK) your database would end up storing numbers instead of strings. You could use a CHECK constraint if you want the database to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a enum type in database and create new column with that type. Check out this article [Rails enum and PostgreSQL enum](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/b492fb26ec-rails-enums-and-postgresql-enums).

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be adding a method for string pattern validation in transactions controller for `create` action like below. You can find more info about callbacks [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

```
before_action :validate_transaction_type, only: [:create]
```

Comment: I'm looking to do this at the migration level and not in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what the user that asked the question wanted but I ended up here trying to do a similar validation on a string column. For other people that come to this question. Another way of adding validations is to use the `inclusion:` [validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) inside the model.

It will go as follows:

```
validates :cuteness, inclusion: { within: %w(not meh okay kinda-cute), message: "%{value} is not a valid cuteness level" }
```

it can also be re-written as `validates_inclusion_of`:

```
  validates_inclusion_of :age, :in => 0..20 , message: "%{value} is not between 0 and 20"
```

Lastly, note that the keyworkd `within:` is an alias of `in:` so both should work.